# URL rewriting not working on wamp server

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, wamp

Hi i am trying to practice the url rewriting. I have written .htaccess file in the path : C:\wamp64\www\RewriteUrl.  At the same location i have file pet_care_info_01_02_2008.php . My rewrite rule  is:

```
   RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
   RewriteRule    ^pet-care/?$    pet_care_info_01_02_2008.php    [NC,L]
```

So i want http://localhost/RewriteUrl/pet_care_info_01_02_2008.php to be changed to http://localhost/RewriteUrl/pet-care.php. But currently it gives me the whole path and not rewriting it.Any idea?

Comment: http://localhost/RewriteUrl/pet_care_info_01_02_2008.php thats the command which i am typing in URL and it doesn't give me http://localhost/RewriteUrl/pet-care.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

# To externally redirect pet_care_info_ to pet_care.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /pet_care_info_ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /RewriteUrl/pet_care\.php [R=301,L]

RewriteRule    ^pet_care\.php$    pet_care_info_01_02_2008.php    [NC,L]
```

Because that's the way you explain it ...
And try with `/RewriteUrl/pet_care.php`

Comment: The requested URL /RewriteUrl/pet_care.php was not found on this server. it gives me this if i change my rule like you said. I want the php page to change to pet_care.ph p from localhost  but it isn't. It opens the normal page  with URL
localhost/RewriteUrl/pet_care_info_01_02_2008.php

Comment: It's `pet-care` in your question !!! not `pet_care`. I change that now in my answer.

Comment: YES now it works but can my orignal url localhost/RewriteUrl/pet_care_info_01_02_2008.php be automatically shown as pet-care.php. Because right now i can access using both urls.?

Comment: I added that in my answer

Comment: Well it doesnot work. It doesn't externally redirect me. I get the same URL unless accessed by pet_care.php

Comment: I placed it at the root, which is not the place. Use my new rule

Comment: well thanks alot it works. Could you recommend any link to learn about the url rewriting rules. Thanks

Comment: There are many, but the base is here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html